# How can declare a Jquery Object before it exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to declare a Jquery Object befor it exists.

I explain my problem :

I'm building an application with jQuery and i organize my code like it is explained in jQuery documentation here : https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

I have wrote a code similar to this :

```
var foo = {
   init : function(){
       foo.config = {
           element : $('.myDiv')
       }
   }
};

var bar = {
    fooBar : function(){
        $(someData).each(function(){
            $('.anotherDiv').append("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
        });

        foo.config.element.click(function(){
            alert('It doesn\'t works for me');
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    foo.init();
    bar.fooBar();
});
```

So, when i click on the div the alert is not displayed. I know the existence of delegate() or on() method but it doesn't work neither.

I think it's because when the page is loaded the object doesn't exists yet.

Is my hypothesis viable?

Comment: `on()` is the solution, we can't tell why it doesn't work for you because you didn't show us your attempt to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for the DOM element not at the moment of `foo.init();` execution, but at the moment you need the element - to assign its `click` handler.

Change `element` to function:

```
var foo = {
   init : function(){
       foo.config = {
           element : function() { return $('.myDiv'); } 
       }
   }
};

var bar = {
    fooBar : function(){
        $(someData).each(function(){
            $('.anotherDiv').append("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
        });

        foo.config.element().click(function(){
            alert('It doesn\'t works for me');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this works like a charm, but can you explain why?

Comment: @JohnnyBeGoody - it worked because `$('.myDiv')` searches for a DOM element not at the moment when you call `foo.init();`, but at the moment you call  `foo.config.element()`.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't exist yet, you need to use `.on` - following your design above and provided there is some container that is present on page load:

```
foo.config = {
    //element : $('.myDiv'),
    element: ".myDiv",
    container: $("body")
}
```

Handler:

```
foo.config.container.on("click", foo.config.element, function(){

});
```

Comment: element  needs to be string

Comment: @Quentin Check `this` in handler, it is the container so means selector param isn't used (it is used as data handler instead). You could still filter event target but that's not the point here  (sorry, don't know how to update jsbin)

Comment: @Quentin try `alert(this.tagName)//BODY` ... clicking outside could also be because body has no height beyond the element

Comment: @Quentin See jsFiddle (jsbin makes me sick...) https://jsfiddle.net/65n0ah11/  Click button.  And DOC for jq `on()` method is clear, if second param isn't a string, then it is used as data handler. EDIT: doc says: `data
Type: Anything` i guess anything but not a function though

Comment: @Quentin  body height isn't viewport height by default

Comment: huh. Looks like I was misinterpreting something horribly. http://jsbin.com/vubeda/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: This is what i did to get around the problem, but, is it possible to bind the click to the object directly?

Comment: @JohnnyBeGoody -- Don't create the handler until the element exists in the DOM.

Comment: Okay but thus I can not take full advantage of this pattern..?

Answer (score 0):

Your created direct

> ```
> var foo = {
>    init : function(){
>        foo.config = {
> ```
>
> direct selection of items for the moment (no one created yet)
>
> ```
>            element : $('.myDiv')
>        }
>    }
> };
>
> var bar = {
>     fooBar : function(){
>         $(someData).each(function(){
>             $('.anotherDiv').append("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
>         });
> ```
>
> You bind handler for empty group
>
> ```
>         foo.config.element.click(function(){
>             alert('It doesn\'t works for me');
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

You can use indirect event handling like this:

```
    var foo = {
        init: function() {
```

Created indirect click listener on document. One will handle all propagated click events from every .myDiv, even created in future.

```
         $(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function() {
                    alert('This mast work on any created div with class "myDiv"');
                });
                foo.config = {
                    elementSelector: '.myDiv'
                }
            }
        };
    var bar = {
        fooBar : function(){
            $(someData).each(function(){
                $('.anotherDiv').append("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
            });
        }
    }
```